# Srivaishnava scriptures/acharyas mentioning Pandharpur

Tags: temple, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, vitthal

Pandharpur is one of the sacred place for Vaishnavas. 
Is there any Srivaishnava work or some Srivaishnava acharya's injunctions revering Pandharpur as sacred place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Sri Vaishnava Acharya Vedanta Desikan mentions Pandharpur as a sacred place of Vishnu in [this excerpt](http://preview.ibb.co/n3KKma/image.jpg) from the the beginning of his play "Sankalpa Suryodaya":

> Esteemed Gentry! I am bid by this august assembly composed of saintly men like yourselves, who, in order to witness festivals, have trod far and wide over several holy places like Srirangam, Tirupati, Kanchipura, Tirunarayanapuram, Puroshottama and **Panduranga** where our (Sarveshvara), the Blezzed Lord is installed, - the Lord before whose lotus feet the gem-set diadems of myriads if Devas and Asuras form, as it were, so many waving lights, - the Lord whose vow always is to protect all who seek refuge of Him, whose duties are right-well done with lotus-born Lakshmi cooperate, - Who like the cloud (rain), quencheth the wild-fire of mundane misery.

The sacred places of Vishnu named are Sri Rangam, Tirupati, Kanchipuram, Melkote, Puri, and Pandharpur.